# Form validation Jquery no error

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to validate a very simple form with javascript using '.submit()' function.
The first if statement (name is ok) but it doesn't go into the second one (varsta) and I get no error. If I take out the condition '!$.isNumeric($('#varsta').val())' the script runs fine.
Why is that? Thank you

```
<form method="POST">
  <div>
    <label for="nume">Nume</label>
    <input name="nume" id="nume" type="text">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="varsta">Varsta</label>
    <input name="varsta" id="varsta" type="text">
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Push">
  </div>
</form>


<div id="result"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $( document ).ready(function() {      



    $('form').submit(function(event) {

      event.preventDefault();

      if ($('#nume').val() != "") {

        if ($('#varsta').val() != ""||!$.isNumeric($('#varsta').val())) {

          $('#result').html($('#nume').val() + '<br />' + $('#varsta').val());


        } else {$('#result').text('Indoduceti varsta valida');}



        } else { $('#result').text('Indoduceti numele');}

    })



  })

</script>
```

Comment: jsfiddle would be usefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be like:

```
 if ($('#varsta').val() != "" && !$.isNumeric($('#varsta').val())) {
   ...
 } else {
   ...
 }
```

Comment: @tavi_tudor can you be a little more specific?

Comment: Sorry.. both statements cannot be true at the same time. The input either null or has a value that can be numeric or not

Comment: You are right. I was used from PHP to verify inputs the other way.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$.isNumeric()` try `isNaN()` as shown :

```
if ($('#varsta').val() != "" || isNaN($('#varsta').val()))
{......}
```

Comment: @tavi_tudor..i think above answer will work for you if need more help then plz comment.

Comment: @tavi_tudor...try reversing the condition use(not operator)!isNaN($('#varsta').val() instead of isNaN($('#varsta').val()

Comment: same result. It is driving me nuts

Comment: @tavi_tudor..strange..just check carefully there must be problem somewhere else...

Comment: If i take out the 'isNan' or 'isNumereic' 'if' condition the script goes well. So there must be a problem with this condition